# Como hacer git push a varias ramas a la vez

Tags: git, github

Resulta que yo tengo todo mi proyecto de forma local y en el transcurso del desarrollo fui creando muchas ramas. Y ahora quiero llevarlo a un repositorio remoto en github, entonces como puedo hacer push de todas las ramas a la vez a mi repositorio remoto, para no tener que hacer `git push origin 'rama'`, con todas las ramas que tengo.

Answer (score 2):

lo puedes hacer con este comando

```
git push --all
```

Fuente:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Answer (score 1):

Puedes especificar varias ramas de un solo tanganazo a un remoto:

```
git push el-remoto rama1 rama2 rama3
```

Comment: de un solo tanganazo xD

Comment: @Ivandez Podría colocar _guamazo_ que también suena bien autóctono. XD